# Can't find the first element of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get the first element of a dict, "names(1)" doesn't work.

```
names = {"John":20, "Marc":22, "Dwayne":23}
print(names(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first element of it (only in versions with ordered dictionaries) with

```
print(next(iter(names)))
```

In `names = {"John":20, "Marc":22, "Dwayne":23}` outuput is `"John"`

Comment: What versions have ordered dictionaries?

Comment: 3.6+ On earlier versions this will just give you a key from the dictionary

Answer (score 5):

First use `iter` to get an iterator of keys out of the dict (this is based on insertion order as of python 3.6+). Then use `next()` to get the first item (first key) from that iterator:

```
names = {"John": 20, "Marc": 22, "Dwayne": 23}
print(next(iter(names)))
```

Result:

```
John  # first according to insertion order
```